# "The omelette is already cooked"?

Tags: word-choice, proverbs

Today I saw a proverb introduced in a book. The writer said, " "The omelette is already cooked"means it is too late to change what has already been done. I think the phrase is similar to "there is no use crying over spilled milk".

I googled the phrase and however no page about this phrase has existed. I looked the word up in Cambridge Dictionaries Online and it has the entry "You can't make an omelette without breaking eggs", but not the one abovementioned.

Can some native English speakers be so kind to say whether "The omelette is already cooked" really existed?

Comment: Of course it does, and even better, you have a book that proves it.  In so far as they both talk about "what's done is done." they are similar, but your omelette phrase is saying, "it's too late to change it" while the milk phrase is saying, "Don't get stuck on it; move on"

Comment: You might want to check out [ell.se], which might be a more fitting home for some of your questions. More info is available [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it is an expression of another language that was simply translated into English. And I think the image is not without wit, in any case the image is very good. In my mind I imagine a waiter saying to a guest who wants to change his order:
Sorry, the omelette is already cooked.

Thanks to Laure we know now that this beautiful saying comes from China. See Laure's link below.

Comment: Indeed. It's a Chinese saying meaning "deadline is past". A good explanation [here](http://news.stheadline.com/dailynews/headline_news_detail_columnist.asp?id=127970&section_name=wtt&kw=126).

Comment: Very good hint, Laure.

Comment: Don't hesitate to add the link to your answer, comments are perishable goods, answers are more long lasting.

Comment: @Laure  I have mentioned your information and link in my answer.

Comment: That link does not claim that this is a Chinese saying at all.  The writer is not Chinese, he is merely giving tips about English to his Chinese readers.

Comment: Okay, whoever wants to know the exact origin of this saying is free to do more research. At least the saying sounds Chinese.

Comment: Laure, the link you cite is where I saw the text. No proof that comes from a Chinese saying.